# Release on remote environment TFS2018

Tags: tfs, tfsbuild

My team is asked to put in place a continuous delivery pipeline in place and as I am very new to release management with TFS 2018 I am wondering if the following scenario is possible with TFS :

- we will have to deploy our artifacts in our dev environnement (on the same environment as our TFS server) all of this in a more or less continuous process if possible and later with a manual validation we would like to push the validated version of the system on a remote QA environment . There is an acces on internet via http to our TFS server.

  => is it possible to install agents on the remote QA machines and pull and deploy artefacts on the internet ? If not, is there any over workaround ?

Thank you for your time.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

It will always be possible, as long as the remote QA Machines have "line-of-sight" on your TFS Instance. If you can access TFS from the remote QA Machines, then your deployment agents should work as well